# Regex to find whole string given start and end position in document

Tags: regex, eclipse

I'm trying to come up with a regex to use in the Eclipse Find/replace dialog that will find a string that are between two points.

For example, I want to find "code" in:

`12345    code  acb=12ab3cd`

"code" is at position 12 (1 index base).

`(?<=^.{9}.{0,8})code` works - which searches between 10 and 18 in the editor.

But `(?<=^.{7}.{0,5})code` also returns true. Even though the end is in the middle of the search String. Start/ end positions are 8 and 13.

How do I make sure it only captures the whole word within the range?

Comment: `  12345    code  acb=12ab3cd` there are supposed to be two spaces at the beginning

Comment: I've edited your post to add insecable spaces that aren't trimmed at display

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem (what is the range supposed to be?), but `(?<=^.{7}.{0,5})code` (which could be written more concisely as `(?<=^.{7,12})code`) matches "code" preceded by 7 to 12 characters after the start of the string ; those characters do not include the "code" pattern. In your example there are 11 characters between the start of the string and `code`, so it is matched.

Comment: `(?<=^.{9}.{0,8})` is a variable length look behind. What engine (or plugin) are you using. Also, you don't need look around anyway. A simple `^.{start,end}code` should work. If it were a PCRE/Perl style engine then this `^.{start,end}\Kcode`

Comment: Just a fyi, when you say `between two points` I assume you mean where the literal starts. If not, you must take into account the length of the literal, and that must be less than the difference between the two points, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may move the lookbehind to the end of the pattern.

```
code(?<=^.{9}.{0,8})
```

Now, the check if made *after* matching `code` and it will only be matched if there are any 9  chars (other than line break chars) and then any 0 to 8 chars (other than line break chars) immediately to the left of the current location (i.e. the one after `code`).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=code%28%3F%3C%3D%5E.%7B9%7D.%7B0%2C8%7D%29&i=%20%2012345%20%20%20%20code%20%20acb%3D12ab3cd), also tested at [Java regex compatible OCPSoft regex tester](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/):

[image]